# Why does x64 console app can refer 32 bit Oracle.DataAccess.dll without any exception

Tags: c#, oracle

This is a console application to update Oracle database. It refers to Oracle.DataAccess.dll in 32 bit. Here is the core code about database operation.

```
            using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(DataSource))
            {
                using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = paraText;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Connection = connection;
                        cmd.Connection.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        FileLog.Error("UpdateActiveStatus", ex, LogType.Error);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        cmd.Connection.Close();
                        cmd.Connection.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
```

I set the console application platform target as x64, while the oracle dll is in 32 bit. But it works! Why? In my opinion, x64 app cannot refer x86 dll.

To make sure that the application is running in x64, I go to Task Manager and find the console app process is indeed in x64 mode.

Why? x64 console appliation with 32 bit dll without any bad format dll exception?

Edit: Here is more information about version.

This is how the console app is set.
[image]

This is the oracle dll it refers to.
[image]

This is the oracle dll version detect.
[image]

**Edit:
I get the conclusin that it finds out this x64 dll from GAC now. But how does it know which version it should use? There are different oracle client installed in my local machine.**

Comment: Are you sure you have the 32-bit Oracle DLL? Check with [Sigcheck](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sigcheck)

Comment: @wernfried-domscheit, sure. I updated some information. This can confirm this is a 32 bit oracle dll.

Comment: Check with [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) which DLL is actually loaded. Perhaps it is loaded from GAC which takes precedence over the local file.

Comment: Hi @wernfried-domscheit, is there any other tool to detect the dll it is actually loaded? Process Monitor cannot start at my computer due to company computer's policy.

Comment: Hi @wernfried-domscheit, finally I find the answer. I loged typeof(OracleConnection).Assembly.Location in my log file. And it turns out to be C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\Oracle.DataAccess\2.112.3.0__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.DataAccess.dll

Comment: Yes, `typeof(OracleConnection).Assembly.Location` is the correct way of doing it. However, it does not tell you the search path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For strong name assembly, the first search choice is GAC, and then it is bin folder.

Answer (score -1):

Fianally I find out the root cause.

The console app is not using the x86 version oracle dll, instead, it using the one in GAC!

Here is how I find out this. If we are not sure which dll we get the class from, we can use `typeof(OracleConnection).Assembly.Location` to get the location of the really loaded assembly, which the class is in. Here I find that it is C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\Oracle.DataAccess\2.112.3.0__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.DataAccess.dll !

In summary, how x64 console app using oracle dll. It is true for all strong name assembly.

1. It will check in GAC. If it finds the correct one, it uses it.
2. If it not finds the correct oracle dll in GAC, it will serach the app bin folder..

Comment: Your summary is **very** simplified, in reality it is more complex. The correct procedure you can find at [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies)